# How to remove the blank text boxes from python pptx generated slides?

Tags: python, textbox, powerpoint, python-pptx

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation("my_pptfile_begin.pptx")

left = Inches(0.6)
top = Inches(1.7)

blank_slide_1 = prs.slide_layouts[6]
add_the_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_1)
img_path1 = 'Three_Part_Set_Difference_excel_printout.png'
slide1=prs.slides[1]
pic = slide1.shapes.add_picture(img_path1, left, top)

blank_slide_2 = prs.slide_layouts[6]
add_the_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_2)
img_path2 = 'my_image.png'
slide2=prs.slides[2]
pic = slide2.shapes.add_picture(img_path2, left, top)

logoleft = Inches(4.7)
logotop = Inches(1.8)

blank_slide_3 = prs.slide_layouts[6]
add_the_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_3)
img_path3 = 'logo_slide.png'
slide3=prs.slides[3]
pic = slide3.shapes.add_picture(img_path3, logoleft, logotop)

prs.save('my_pptfile_Final.pptx')
```

How to remove the blank text boxes (or as a matter of fact all textboxes)?

I do not need any text boxes in my Powerpoint output file

Comment: or at least remove textboxes for 1 slide

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about empty placeholder shapes, just use a slide layout that has no placeholders.

In the default template used when you call `Presentation()` by itself (without an argument), that is the seventh layout I believe (`prs.slide_layouts[6]`).

But you need to adjust that for whatever starting .pptx file you're using ("my_pptfile_begin.pptx" in your case) by looking at it in slide-master view and counting down to the blank layout (or adding one if it doesn't have one).

Comment: Thanks,  It seems my company's default template goes up to double digits.  Python only uses this default template whereby 17 is the slide with no text boxes. Thus  blank_slide_3 = prs.slide_layouts[16] did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

blank_slide_3 = prs.slide_layouts[x]  where x the slide number of the default template of your pptx application or your company's default template.

Therefore you need to know the default template and know the blank slide with no textboxes of that template based on the defaults of **your ppt application**